# Play framework: Migration issue "HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table <table name> add column _ebean_intercept binary(255)"

Tags: java, postgresql, playframework

Models file looks like:

```
@Entity
public class Person {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
  public String id;
  public String name;
}
```

Database used is postgres, while applying migration it gave this error:

```
[error] o.h.t.h.SchemaUpdate - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table Person add column _ebean_intercept binary(255)
[error] o.h.t.h.SchemaUpdate - ERROR: type "binary" does not exist
```

While at controllers level its giving these error:

```
1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/avaje/ebean/bean/EntityBean
at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider.<init>(DefaultJPAApi.java:39)
at play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider.class(DefaultJPAApi.java:34)
while locating play.db.jpa.DefaultJPAApi$JPAApiProvider
while locating play.db.jpa.JPAApi
for parameter 0 at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction.<init>(TransactionalAction.java:20)
while locating play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction
```

My controllers look like:

```
public class Application extends Controller {

@Transactional
public Result addPerson() {
    Person person = Form.form(Person.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    JPA.em().persist(person);
    return redirect(routes.Application.index());
}
.....
```

What may be causing this issue, what is concept of "_ebean_intercept" column ? Let me know if more information needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jar for ebean version 2.7.2 see [ebean dependencies](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.avaje/ebean/2.7.2/)

Comment: As per docs i've these 2 entries:

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "3.0.0")

lazy val myProject = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)

Anyother thing which should be added ?